# can't get React onClick to fire

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, dom-events

I am attempting to teach myself react. I seem to be having issues with getting events to fire off. At this point all I am trying to do is use the useState hook to get and set a button. The button initially renders with the correct value of 100. I am expecting the button to update to 999 when I click the button. Thanks in advance for your time!

**Below is in a file called UserInterface.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import InputElement from "./InputElement";

const useAppState = () => {
  const [numberOfButtonClicks, setnumberOfButtonClicks] = useState(100);

  const setAppState = () => {
    setnumberOfButtonClicks(999);
  };

  return { numberOfButtonClicks, setAppState };
};

const UserInterface = () => {
  const { numberOfButtonClicks, setAppState } = useAppState();

  return (
    <InputElement onClick={setAppState} numClicks={numberOfButtonClicks} />
  );
};

export default UserInterface;
```

**Below is in a file called InputElement.js**

```
import React from "react";

const InputElement = (props) => (
  <button onClick={() => props.onClick()}>{props.numClicks}</button>
);

export default InputElement;import React from "react";
```

Comment: Your code is fine, you've just copied `import React from "react";` twice by accident at the bottom of `InputElement.js`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `<InputElement onClick={setAppState} ... />`  to `<InputElement onClick={() => setAppState(999)} ... />`
and button should be `<button onClick={props.onClick}>{props.numClicks}</button>`